# Graph API get employeeNumber

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

my problem is that i need the employeenumber, which i can't get via the graph api.
In azure ad the data is located in the attribute editor.
The question is how do i get these attributes from the editor?

the code in visual studio is:

```
    public static Task<IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage> GetUsersAsync()
    {
        EnsureGraphForAppOnlyAuth();
        _ = _appClient ??
            throw new System.NullReferenceException("Graph has not been initialized for app-only auth");

        return _appClient.Users
            .Request()
            .Select(u => new
            {
                // Only request specific properties
                u.DisplayName,
                u.GivenName,
                u.Surname,
                u.Id,
                u.EmployeeId,
                u.MobilePhone,
                u.BusinessPhones,
                u.Mail,
                u.CompanyName,
                u.City,
                u.UserPrincipalName,
                u.OnPremisesExtensionAttributes
                
            })
            .Expand(u => u.Manager)
            .Top(999)
            .OrderBy("DisplayName")
            .GetAsync();
    }
```

[image: Picture in azure ad]

I already did some research in the documentation but just found a beta api endpoint for employees.
Also its possible to access through the powershell, but i need to get the employeenumber in visual studio.

Comment: In Azure AD, it will be synced as extension_<appID>_employeeNumber. Try fetching that extension attribute from c#.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I ran below beta api endpoint in [**Graph Explorer**](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) that included `employeeNumber` in **response** normally like this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/<userID>
```

**Response:**

[image]

To get the same **response** from v1 api endpoint, you need to use `select` query parameters explicitly as below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/6587fca0-49c9-41b5-acfd-53cd95ce9e30?$select=id,displayName,extension_<appID>_employeeNumber
```

**Response:**

[image]

You can make use of below **sample code** in c# to get same details:

```cs
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "3f5c7a77-062d-426c-8582-xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var clientId = "376f340a-7b96-40c6-89fbxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

var result = await graphClient.Users["6587fca0-49c9-41b5-acfd-xxxxxxxxxxx"].GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "id", "displayName", "extension_376f340a7b9640xxxxxxxxxxxxxx_employeeNumber" };
});
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Employeenumber not synced even i added to directory extension - Microsoft Q&A by **AmanpreetSingh - MSFT**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/176736/employeenumber-not-synced-even-i-added-to-director)